# DISKPART vs PowerShell Get-Volume

Tags: powershell, disk-partitioning

In `DISKPART.EXE`, I get the info when multiple mount points are assigned to a volume. In the picture we see that Drive G: can also be accessed using D:\SQL\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\DATA\ or D:\BlaBla:

[image: DISKPART result]

But I can't find the same info using PowerShell's `Get-Volume` or `Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Volume`. Does anyone knows how to extract this info using a native PowerShell function?

[image: Get-Volume result]

I thought of extracting the info by calling `DISKPART.EXE` inside PowerShell but I would prefer an native PowerShell function like `Get-Volume`.

Comment: Did you try piping get-volume into select-object -property * to see what properties are available in the output?

Comment: It looked like a good idea. I did try, it does not provide the information I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps surprisingly, you can look up mount points via the [`Win32_MountPoint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394205.aspx) class:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_MountPoint | Select-Object Directory, Volume
```

Further details can be obtained by looking up the references:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_MountPoint | ForEach-Object {
    $dir = [wmi]$_.Directory | Select-Object -Expand Name
    $vol = [wmi]$_.Volume
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        Directory   = $dir
        Label       = $vol.Label
        DriveLetter = $vol.DriveLetter
        FileSystem  = $vol.FileSystem
        DeviceId    = $vol.DeviceId
    }
}
```